# Using a Street Address in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod

Is there anyway to take in a Street Address ("1234 Test Ave. New York, NY) and be able to create an annotation for a map? Basically my app current marks the users location and I want to make the location of an event (A button pushes the mapView on screen). I want to obtain the coordinates of that event so that I can place an annotation on the mapView that is being displayed on screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate GPS coordinates into addresses you can use MKReverseGeocoder, to translate addresses into GPS coordinates you need to use a 3rd party geocoding tool or write a wrapper for some service yourself. I wrote one for one of my apps and open sourced it. [Check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/mjisrawi/iOS-Geocoding-Services)